# Spring cloud config - Share file or his location

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config

I have two applications :

- one spriig boot config server
- the another one a spring boot config client

The client side have to use a file named **certificate.json**.

I want to store this file in the server side so another microprogram and my client programm who need it can retrieve it from the server side.

**I try that :**

- copy the file **certificate.json** to classpath:/config
- add this line to the application.properties :

  certificate.location: classpath:config/certificate.json
- call the value from client programm by :

  @Value("${certificate.location}")
  private String certificateLocation;

But the value of certificateLocation is **classpath:config/certificate.json**. The value I want is the file location like : /home/user/project/scr/main/resources/config/certificate.json.

Or, are there a way to directly retrieve my file by URI, for example locahost:8889/... (8889 is my config server port).

**EDIT 1:** 
I cannot use absolute path from the server because I'm not the one who run it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you think about exposing the REST endpoint to return that file as a resource, so another side can use `new UrlResource("http://my.server/certificate.json")`  ?

Comment: Good idea @Artem Bilan! I'll try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do

```
@Value("${certificate.location}") private Resource certificateLocation;
```

that way, your location is already a [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) that you can load, call [getURI()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#getURI--), [getFile()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#getFile--).[getAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) etc. Since your value is prefixed with `classpath:`, you would have a ClassPathResource instance, which you can use for lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

The `classpath` is just a protocol part of the URL. You can use `file` or any other supported protocol. For example, `file://home/user/project/scr/main/resources/config/certificate.json`.

Comment: yes but, I don't know the absolute path of server project! And also, the client and server application may be on different machine so the client dont see the file://

Comment: Have you tried Spring Integration SFTP Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming

Comment: OP wants to know the absolute location of a file he specifies from classpath, and you're suggesting "spring integration SFTP streaming inbound channel adapter"?

Answer (score 1):

[Try this url](https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-and-spring-cloud-config-server)

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations
=file://${user.home}/CentralRepo/
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=native
I am also get this way using microservice
```

Comment: try this also  https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/07/17/microservices-configuration-with-spring-cloud-config/

Answer (score 1):

OP you need to create a web service and return certificate.json as the response. Then you can send and receive data by sending a GET or POST request to a URI like https://12.12.12.12:8080/getCertificate. Please see:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

As a side note, you should never expose your inner files to the internet because it's very unsecure and opens you up to pirating and hacking.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in this case is

1. Add configuration for static folder

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication public class DemoStaticresourceApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(DemoStaticresourceApplication.class, args);
       }

       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**").addResourceLocations("file:/fileFolder/")
                   .setCachePeriod(0);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Place certificate.json in fileFolder and try http://localhost:8080/files/certificate.json and it will be served directly from file system for you.

And now every file you add in this folder will be served only if called using /files/ path